# Is it possible to inject dependencies into an NServiceBus Message Mutator?

Tags: nservicebus

I'd like to inject a dependency into an NServiceBus Message Mutator... since the lifetime of the Mutators is controlled by NServiceBus (and NSB wants a paramaterless constructor), constructor injection won't work...

any ideas?

UPDATE: Here is the code:

```
public class AddTransactionInformationToOutgoingHeaders : 
                            IMutateOutgoingTransportMessages, 
                            INeedInitialization
{
    private readonly IProvideTransactionInformation transactionInformationProvider;

    public void Init()
    {
        Configure.Instance.Configurer.ConfigureComponent<AddTransactionInformationToOutgoingHeaders>(DependencyLifecycle.InstancePerCall);
    }

    public AddTransactionInformationToOutgoingHeaders()
    {
    }

    public AddTransactionInformationToOutgoingHeaders(IProvideTransactionInformation transactionInformationProvider)
    {
        this.transactionInformationProvider = transactionInformationProvider;
    }

    public void MutateOutgoing(object[] messages, TransportMessage transportMessage)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

}

If I take away the empty ctor, I get this error message thrown from my ConfigureBus() call in Global.asax:
"No parameterless constructor defined for this object."

Answer (score 2):

To get around this, I just kept one empty constructor for NServiceBus and then created a overloaded constructor that took my dependency that is managed by Unity.

It works.

Didn't know that mutators could work like that. It was my first time trying to inject a dependency into one.

UPDATE:

I got around this by using property injection on the mutator instead:

```
public class AddTransactionInformationToOutgoingHeaders : IMutateOutgoingTransportMessages, INeedInitialization
{
    public IProvideTransactionInformation TransactionInformationProvider { get; set; }

    public void Init()
    {
        Configure.Instance.Configurer.ConfigureComponent<AddTransactionInformationToOutgoingHeaders>(DependencyLifecycle.InstancePerCall);
    }

    public void MutateOutgoing(object[] messages, TransportMessage transportMessage)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Worked perfectly.

Comment: that sounds like a bug. can u raise an issue here https://github.com/Particular/NServiceBus/issues

Comment: INeedInitialization requires a parameterless ctor. Try to move it to a separate class?

Comment: Adreas, I just ended up using property injection. INeedInitializatino gets the paramaterless ctor it needs, and my class code looks a lot tidier! Thanks for the help. FYI, watched your NServiceBus PluralSite vid, it was great! Got me started on message mutators. Any plans to do a medium to advanced level NSB tutorial on PluralSite any time soon?

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure both constructor and property injection should work. What is the exception?

Comment: Andreas, do you know of any code example of a mutator that has something injected in the constructor, using StructureMap? I can't get it working, tried following advice in this post and others...

Comment: Never mind, I got it working. I was missing a `Component.Configure` for my object's sub-objects. It pays to read the *full* exception details...

Comment: Glad you got it going!